# Lambda query with many to many relation in Entity framework 4

Tags: entity-framework, lambda, many-to-many

I've 5 tables:

- Game
- Category
- GameCategory
- Movie
- MovieCategory

GameCategory is simply the relation between Game and Category. (many to many)
Same for MovieCategory with movie.

Now I just want to know how to get all Category that are in relation with a game.

For the moment I use this query :

```
Query(c => c.Game.Count > 0).Distinct().ToList();
```

But this query have bad performance (about 500ms) whereas if I use the query direclty in sql server with sql management

```
SELECT category_id
FROM  [GameCategory]
Group by category_id
```

it takes less than 0.008 ms.

What is the best lambda expression query to have the same result ?

(With Entity framework I can't access to GameCategory directly because it hidden by the framework)

Need your help

Thankssss

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

Consider using Query(c => c.Game.Any()).Distinct().ToList(); instead of Query(c => c.Game.Count > 0).Distinct().ToList();